# What is the format of logstash config file

Tags: serialization, logstash

Does logstash use its own file syntax in config file? Is there any parser or validator for config file syntax?

For anyone that does not use logstash but have idea about file formats here is a sample syntax:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/messages"
    type => "syslog"
  }

  file {
    path => "/var/log/apache/access.log"
    type => "apache"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can now check configuration when calling logstash with `--configtest` switch. I also wonder what this format is (meaning is it inspired by something, or just their own idea).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently command line arguments have been updated since the answers have been posted and `--configtest` and `--config` arguments are no longer valid. In order to ask Logstash (at least v5) to validate config file:

```
bin/logstash -t -f config.conf
```

With expanded arguments it looks like this:

```
bin/logstash --config.test_and_exit --path.config config.conf
```

Answer (score 31):

The Logstash configuration file is a custom format developed by the Logstash folks using [Treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/).

The grammar itself is described in the source file [`grammar.treetop`](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/be914390f2749843f588cfba65eca133ff729308/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/grammar.treetop) and compiled using Treetop into the custom [`grammar.rb`](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/be914390f2749843f588cfba65eca133ff729308/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/grammar.rb) parser.

That parser is then [used by the `pipeline.rb`](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/be914390f2749843f588cfba65eca133ff729308/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb#L42-L50) file in order to set up the pipeline from the Logstash configuration.

If you're not that much into Ruby, there's another interesting project called [node-logstash](https://github.com/bpaquet/node-logstash) which provides a Logstash implementation in Node.js. The configuration format is exactly the same as with the official Logstash, though the parser is obviously a different one written for Node.js. In this project, the Logstash [configuration file grammar](https://github.com/bpaquet/node-logstash/blob/master/lib/logstash_config.jison) is described in [jison](https://github.com/zaach/jison) and the parser is also [automatically generated](https://github.com/bpaquet/node-logstash/blob/master/lib/logstash_config.js), but could be used by any Node.js module simply by requiring that generated parser.

Comment: This might change a bit once the [Logstash Intermediate Representation](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/6018) comes to life.

Comment: I don't think Logstash Intermediate Representation ever came to life.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following command to verify your logstash config file is valid:

```
bin/logstash --configtest --config <your config file>
```

Answer (score 1):

So far. there is no any parser or validator for logstash config. You can only use the logstash to verify the config.

For more information about config, you can visit [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html). All the format is introduced in this page.

Answer (score 1):

The [Logstash-Config Go package](https://github.com/breml/logstash-config) config provides a ready to use parser and Abstract Syntax Tree for Logstash configuration files in Go.

The basis of the grammar for the parsing of the Logstash configuration format is the original [Logstash Treetop grammar](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/master/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/grammar.treetop) .

logstash-config uses [pigeon](https://github.com/mna/pigeon) to generate the parser from the PEG (parser expression grammar).