# I want to know if there is way that Logstash config file can be edited either via command prompt or some kind of a script say a Python script.

Tags: python, bash, command-line, logstash, logstash-configuration

I tried reading the .config like a .json file in Python but it throws error. Obviously reading it like a text file line by line works but editing the file like this is very cumbersome.

Is there anyway we can edit the fields of logstash?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34962284/677561

Comment: What is the text editor have you tried? What is the error message while saving file? Logstash config file can be edited by vim, vi or nano editors.